# CSS transform scale: which box is scaled?

Tags: css, css-transforms

When using the CSS `transform: scale(2,2);` on an element, is it that element's content-box, padding-box, border-box, or margin-box that is to become scaled?

(I have a intuitive feeling that the answer is border-box, but I need confirmation.)

Comment: All of them are scaled

Comment: @vals Well, since they are subsets of each other, I suspect that only one box is to become scaled. But thanks anyway ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element's box is scaled in its entirety, so the answer in terms of the CSS2 box model would be margin-box, since that's what an element's box usually refers to. But no one refers to an element's box in those terms.

Comment: When I started out learning CSS, the tutorials/books indeed introduced the terms content-box, padding-box, border-box and margin-box. I find them useful as to help learning the CSS basics and also to be intuitive. A few years later when the property box-sizing was introduced, I noticed that some of these terms were reused -- now as distinct values for that property. But you are correct in that my question is not about box-sizing.

Comment: @Goran W: Those terms are still useful - but only when referring to the box model. When speaking about element boxes in general, they're not usually used.